# Help with Rails Seeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following seeds.rb file:

```
initial_users = User.create(
[
{
    :first_name => "Joe", 
    :last_name => "Smith",
    :address1 => "123 Anywhere St.",
    :city => "San Francisco",
    :state => "CA",
    :zip => "12345",
    :phone => "123-456-1234",
    :password => "password"
},
{
    :first_name => "Jane", 
    :last_name => "Doe",
    :address1 => "123 Main St.",
    :city => "Los Angeles",
    :state => "CA",
    :zip => "12345",
    :phone => "123-345-4567",
    :password => "password"
}
])
```

But when I run rake db:seed, the rows don't show up in the database even though there isn't any error being reported?  I even tried specifying RAILS_ENV=development but it still doesn't show up.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `create!` which would raise an exception if any of the required attributes are missing. Other than that - i'd suggest random data generators to seed your data for development purposes. Or use some fixture replace for test purposes (check github for blueprints - my favorite).

Comment: thank you... I had some leftover validations :) I'll check out the fixture replace.  Is there a place you recommend to find out more about random data generation besides teh google?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess without seeing your model, but maybe you are missing the password_confirmation field and therefore your validations are failing